# I can't import 'bmp' and 'png' image into my pygame,

Tags: python, image, pygame

Here is my problem, I have been trying to import the 'bmp' image as my icon but when I run it, but when I run it it says `pygame.error: Unsupported image format`. I have tried both bmp and png format but neither of them works. I am pretty sure the file is in the same directory as `main`.

```py
    import pygame
    pygame.init()

    #Screen
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invader")

    #Title and Icon
    icon = pygame.image.load('ufo.bmp')
    pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

    running = True

    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
```

[image]

Comment: Does `pygame.image.get_extended()` return true or false?

Comment: how large is the image? (resolution and file size)

Answer (score 0):

Either your bmp file is compressed or corrupted and pygame cannot load the file properly, or you have a problem in your setup.

To test if pygame works as expected:

- try running `pygame.image.get_extended()` and see what the output is (True/False).
- create a new png in paint and try loading it. Then you will know whether the image you are trying to load is at fault or whether there is a deeper problem with your setup.

From the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load):

> Pygame will automatically determine the image type (e.g., GIF or bitmap) and create a new Surface object from the data.
>
> [....]
>
> Pygame may not always be built to support all image formats. At
> minimum it will support uncompressed BMP. If
> pygame.image.get_extended() returns 'True', you should be able to load
> most images (including PNG, JPG and GIF).
>
> You should use os.path.join() for compatibility.
>
> eg. asurf = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data', 'bla.png'))

Answer (score 0):

Have you ckecked if the png image was in the same file as the game you can also try clicking in the image and copy its acces path and replace ufo.bmp with it.
or just try adding accent to icon like here and adding file format:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

#Screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invader")

#Title and Icon
icon = pygame.image.load('ufo.bmp')
pygame.display.set_icon('icon.bmp')

running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```